# How to use the :eq selector in Nokogiri

Tags: jquery, ruby, nokogiri

In jQuery you have the `:eq` selector to reduce the set of matched elements to one with a given index.

How can the same be done with Nokogiri? I searched long, but couldn't find a way.

See this example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html ='
<div>
<p>foo</p></div>
<span>
<p>bar</p>
<p>foobar</p></span>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

p doc.search('p:eq(0)')
# -> []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only to reduce the set of matched nodes, is to use Ruby and an array method like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri ... 
doc.search("table")[2].search("...")
```

Neither Nokogiri's XPath nor its CSS selectors support a functonality that is equal to jQuery's `:eq` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I fish:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html ='
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>foobar</p>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('//p[3]')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x811058ac name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x81104f74 "foobar">]>]
```

Nokogiri returned a NodeSet, a collection of nodes that acts like an array. I can search using `at` instead of `search` to retrieve just the node:

```
doc.at('//p[3]').text
=> "foobar"
```

Or it can return the NodeSet and you can have Ruby extract the particular element from it:

```
doc.search('//p')[2].text
=> "foobar"
```

---

```
p doc.search('p:eq(0)')
```

`'p:eq(0)'` isn't CSS, nor is it XPath. It's a jQuery selector added to JavaScript. You can't use jQuery or JavaScript with Nokogiri as an accessor, it has to be CSS or XPath.

---

> Your example doesnt even do what I want. The [i] operator is comparable to the nth-child!

Per [jQuery's documentation for `:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

`//p[3]`, or using `search('p')[2]` to let Ruby slice the NodeSet, will return a specific node. In my examples I'm retrieving the content of the third `<p>` tag, which is the equivalent of jQuery's `:eq(2)`.

Using the same example as before:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html ='
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
<p>foobar</p>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('//p[0]').text
doc.search('//p[1]').text
doc.search('//p[2]').text
doc.search('//p[3]').text

doc.search('//p')[0].text
doc.search('//p')[1].text
doc.search('//p')[2].text
doc.search('//p')[3].text
```

Dumping that into IRB I see:

```
irb(main):011:0* doc.search('//p[0]').text # => ""
irb(main):012:0> doc.search('//p[1]').text # => "foo"
irb(main):013:0> doc.search('//p[2]').text # => "bar"
irb(main):014:0> doc.search('//p[3]').text # => "foobar"

irb(main):015:0> doc.search('//p')[0].text # => "foo"
irb(main):016:0> doc.search('//p')[1].text # => "bar"
irb(main):017:0> doc.search('//p')[2].text # => "foobar"
irb(main):018:0> doc.search('//p')[3].text 
NoMethodError: undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):18
```

Using `//p[1]` is equivalent to using the HTML below with JavaScript and jQuery, loading it in a browser, and looking at the alert, which shows "foo":

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>foobar</p>
    <script>
$().ready(function(){
    alert($('p:eq(0)').text());
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, `//p` with a `[1]` slice in XPath or `[0]` in Ruby, is equivalent to `:eq(0)` in JavaScript. But, since Nokogiri doesn't do JavaScript or jQuery, you have to use either CSS or XPath.

---

jQuery's selectors are available now, making things like this possible:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    this text
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.at('p:contains("foo")').next_sibling.text.strip
=> "this text"
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there an equivalent for css selectors?

Comment: Nokogiri understands CSS and CSS selectors by default. Give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thats why I am asking actually. Check my post.

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you try CSS or jQuery. There's a difference and `:eq` isn't in one. See my edit.

Comment: :eq in jquery would return the first element that is matched. I updated my post with an example that shows that :eq does nothing in nokogiri.

Comment: And, that's my point. Nokogiri parses HTML and XML. It doesn't use JavaScript or jQuery. It understands CSS and XPath accessors only.

Comment: I was asking, if the same functionality as :eq in jquery can be done with any kind of nokogiri????

Comment: Your example doesnt even do what I want. The [i] operator is comparable to the nth-child!

Comment: Support for jQuery selectors is on the roadmap for Nokogiri 2.0. See https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/ROADMAP.md for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Try with  [`:nth-child(N)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) (the first element is find with N = 1)